# why is numba 25% slower when using dicts

Tags: python, numba

I am interested in the performance of numba when using dicts. I did the following experiment:

```
from numpy.random import randint
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def foo_numba(a, b, c):
    N = 100**2
    d = {}
    for i in range(N):
        d[(randint(N), randint(N), randint(N))] = (a, b, c)
    return d


@nb.njit
def test_numba(numba_dict):
    s = 0
    for k in numba_dict:
        s += numba_dict[k][2]
    return s



def foo(a, b, c):
    N = 100**2
    d = {}
    for i in range(N):
        d[(randint(N), randint(N), randint(N))] = (a, b, c)
    return d



def test(numba_dict):
    s = 0
    for k in numba_dict:
        s += numba_dict[k][2]
    return s

a = randint(10, size=10)
b = randint(10, size=10)
c = 1.3

t_numba = foo_numba(a, b, c)
dummy = test_numba(t_numba)
%timeit test_numba(t_numba)
t = foo(a, b, c)
%timeit test(t)
```

To my surpise the output I get is:

```
870 µs ± 6.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1,000 loops each)
654 µs ± 35.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Why is the numba code so much slower than the cPython code? Am I using numba incorrectly?

The slowdown disappears completely if you do either a = tuple(a) or b = tuple(b) (there seems to be no need to do both!).

Comment: Dicts probably don't optimize well at all.

Comment: The benchmark is biased: it includes the compilation time (done during the first call). Without that I get 8.0 µs VS 6.1 µs. Thus Numba is still slower when the compilation time is excluded. 1 µs comes from calling the Numba function since the Numba wrapping function can be quite expensive with complex types like this.

Comment: I have 2 guesses: 1. most of the overhead is spent in the dict so the dict implementation matter more than using compiled code versus interpreted one (eg. hash function causing more collision, less cache-efficient data structure, etc.). CPython dict are surprisingly well optimized in practice but this is quite surprising that Numba is not a bit faster due to the small overhead of the interpreter. 2. The array view management is expensive (it might be that Numba copy the view or even the full array in the worst case).

Comment: One way to remove the overhead of the second point is to use a big array and store `(start,size)` values in the dict. This should be more memory efficient and possibly faster. This enable another optimization : not to use a dict but a specialized data structure for this use case (assuming the indexed numbers are small). Dict are hash-maps internally, and generic hash-maps are often slow.

Answer (score 7):

As Jerome mentions in the comments, the biggest issue here is that you're timing the JIT compilation as part of your benchmark.

Simply adding `test_numba(foo_numba(a, b, c))` before your benchmarks begin will ensure stuff is compiled before the tests, and remove about half of the discrepancy.

Beyond that, your test case is just not something `numba` is particularly useful for. Python's `dict`s are already heavily optimized, and C layer code isn't able to do anything meaningful to further optimize access, unlike with `list`s/`tuple`s (where C layer code can grab the raw storage for direct memory access avoiding many layers of internal function calls involved in doing the same work at the Python level) or `int`s/`float`s (which can again be handled more efficiently by directly extracting the raw C values and performing C level math with less overhead, though modern CPython special-cases simple math like that in the bytecode interpreter to bypass much of that overhead).

In theory, your use of `numpy` arrays *could* benefit from `numba`, but the *way* you're using them means the benefits aren't there. Specifically, your test functions are:

1. (No actual `numpy` types involved) Loading `tuple` of `int`s by iterating a `dict` (`numpy`'s `randint` is returning Python `int`s if you ask for just one value, not `numpy` scalars); `dict` iteration is already heavily optimized, `numba` can't help, and simply loading `tuple`s is not a thing that can be optimized further.
2. (No `numpy` types involved) Looking up said `tuple` in the `dict` again (again, `numba` can't help)
3. (No `numpy` types involved, aside from them being in other indices of the `tuple`) Extracting a single `float` value from the resulting `tuple` (no vectorization can take place)
4. Adding it to `s`. This is the one thing `numba` *could* help with, if it recognizes `s` is *really* `float` (C `double`) for all practical purposes. But again, this is something the most modern versions of Python have optimized quite a bit (by 3.12, the bytecode self-modifies to handle cases where the `+=` always involves `int`s, and bypasses much of the overhead that older Python had to pay for).

In short:

1. `numba` is *never* going to do much for `dict`s
2. `numba`'s gains are best when you're doing a *lot* of uninterrupted simple math, ideally *bulk* math with `numpy` arrays. Extracting single values from a `dict` of `numpy` arrays is not able to overcome the costs `numba` pays in an *attempt* to optimize hard things, that are wasted on easy things.

---

Looking into additional possible causes, I compiled your code against two versions of your code. In both of them, just to be sure types didn't change within the function, I initialized `s` to `0.0`, rather than `0` (since you're summing floats, I wanted it to be a float the whole time). Otherwise, I just triggered compilation, once with `a` and `b` being `numpy` arrays, once with `a` and `b` being converted to `tuple`s first, and used `.inspect_asm()` to dump the output. Most of the generated code is pretty similar, aside from an unrolled `memset` (that only the `numpy` version has) and an unrolled `memcpy` (that both have, but the `tuple` version uses instructions that copy more at a time). The assembly is below for inspection:

`numpy` version:

```
    testq   %rax, %rax
    js  .LBB3_3
    movq    160(%rsp), %rbx
    movq    168(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 32(%rsp)
    movq    176(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 40(%rsp)
    movq    184(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 48(%rsp)
    movq    192(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 56(%rsp)
    movq    200(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 64(%rsp)
    movq    208(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
    movq    216(%rsp), %r13
    movq    224(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 80(%rsp)
    movq    232(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 88(%rsp)
    movq    240(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 96(%rsp)
    movq    248(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 104(%rsp)
    movq    256(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 112(%rsp)
    vmovsd  272(%rsp), %xmm0
    vmovsd  %xmm0, 128(%rsp)
    movq    264(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 120(%rsp)
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    movabsq $NRT_incref, %r14
    callq   *%r14
    movq    %r13, %rdi
    callq   *%r14
    jmp .LBB3_11
.LBB3_4:
    movq    136(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    24(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rcx, (%rdx)
    jmp .LBB3_5
.LBB3_3:
    vxorps  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmovsd  %xmm0, 128(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 120(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 112(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 104(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 96(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 88(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 80(%rsp)
    xorl    %r13d, %r13d
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 64(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 56(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 48(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 40(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, 32(%rsp)
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
.LBB3_11:
    movq    16(%rsp), %rdi
    movq    %r15, %rax
    sarq    $63, %rax
    movq    %rbx, 16(%rsp)
    andnq   %rbx, %rax, %r12
    movq    %r13, %rbx
    andnq   %r13, %rax, %r14
    movabsq $NRT_decref, %r13
    callq   *%r13
    cmpq    $-1, %r15
    je  .LBB3_6
    jge .LBB3_12
    movq    %r12, %rdi
    movabsq $NRT_decref, %rbx
    callq   *%rbx
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    callq   *%rbx
    movabsq $.const.picklebuf.139997182207744, %rax
    jmp .LBB3_7
.LBB3_6:
    movq    %r12, %rdi
    callq   *%r13
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    callq   *%r13
    movabsq $.const.picklebuf.139997182208192, %rax
.LBB3_7:
    movq    24(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, (%rcx)
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .LBB3_5
.LBB3_12:
    movq    16(%rsp), %r13
    movq    %r13, %rdi
    movabsq $NRT_incref, %r15
    callq   *%r15
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   *%r15
    movq    152(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %r13, (%rcx)
    movq    32(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 8(%rcx)
    movq    40(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rcx)
    movq    48(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 24(%rcx)
    movq    56(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 32(%rcx)
    movq    64(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 40(%rcx)
    movq    72(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 48(%rcx)
    movq    %rbx, 56(%rcx)
    movq    80(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 64(%rcx)
    movq    88(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rcx)
    movq    96(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 80(%rcx)
    movq    104(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 88(%rcx)
    movq    112(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 96(%rcx)
    movq    120(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 104(%rcx)
    vmovsd  128(%rsp), %xmm0
    vmovsd  %xmm0, 112(%rcx)
    movq    %r12, %rdi
    movabsq $NRT_decref, %rbx
    callq   *%rbx
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    callq   *%rbx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.LBB3_5:
```

Same section of code for `tuple` version (anchored with the same two leading instructions that don't change):

```
    testq   %rax, %rax
    js  .LBB3_3
    vmovaps 128(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovaps %ymm0, 96(%rsp)
    vmovaps 160(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovaps %ymm0, 32(%rsp)
    vmovaps 192(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovaps %ymm0, 384(%rsp)
    vmovaps 224(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovaps %ymm0, 352(%rsp)
    vmovaps 256(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovaps %ymm0, 320(%rsp)
    vmovsd  288(%rsp), %xmm0
    vmovsd  %xmm0, 24(%rsp)
    movabsq $NRT_decref, %rax
    movq    %r15, %rdi
    vzeroupper
    callq   *%rax
    vmovaps 96(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, (%r13)
    vmovaps 32(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 32(%r13)
    vmovaps 384(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 64(%r13)
    vmovaps 352(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 96(%r13)
    vmovaps 320(%rsp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 128(%r13)
    vmovsd  24(%rsp), %xmm0
    vmovsd  %xmm0, 160(%r13)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp .LBB3_6
.LBB3_5:
    movq    8(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    32(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rcx, (%rdx)
    jmp .LBB3_6
.LBB3_3:
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movabsq $NRT_decref, %rax
    movq    %r15, %rdi
    callq   *%rax
    cmpq    $-1, %rbx
    je  .LBB3_7
    movabsq $.const.picklebuf.139997146496128, %rax
    jmp .LBB3_8
.LBB3_7:
    movabsq $.const.picklebuf.139997145504960, %rax
.LBB3_8:
    movq    32(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, (%rcx)
    movl    $1, %eax
.LBB3_6:
```

All the rest of the code looks pretty similar (small difference here and there; the `tuple` code zeroes a few dozen bytes up front that the `numpy` array doesn't, the `numpy` array code decrefs a couple things the `tuple` doesn't, but nothing on the scale of the difference here.

Comment: I increased the size of the test example and added the dummy computation to eliminate compilation time. A 25% slowdown is more accurate. But I really don't know why changing either a or b to be a tuple should speed things up so much.

Comment: The oddity is that dicts are faster when you use numba in other examples. The oddity here is to do with how numba handles numpy arrays it seems.

Comment: @Simd: Hmm... I've reproduced locally, and used `.inspect_asm()` to dump the generated assembly for each version. I'm not sure what is going on, but it's definitely doing something *very* strange in the code generated when it has `numpy` arrays. It has a huge block of code where it's literally zeroing `eax` over and over again, then writing it to consecutive stack addresses, like an unrolled `memset` to `0`, except it pointlessly rezeroes the already zero `eax` before *every* `mov`; it has another bit that looks like an unrolled `memcpy`.

Comment: What does it do when one of a or b is a tuple?

Comment: The unrolled `memcpy` exists in both versions of the code, but uses more efficient `vmovaps`/`vmovups` instructions for the `tuple` version, and less efficient `movq` (with the odd `vmovsd`) for the `numpy` array code. My best guess would be that it's unnecessarily unpacking the arguments to locals (possibly in both cases), but that the `tuple` code is, for whatever reason, able to assume more stringent alignment, so its unrolled loops uses fewer instructions that copy more data per instruction. I'm not going to fully reverse engineer the compiler output though. It's doing dumb things.

Comment: This is really helpful information. Could you add the offending asm to your answer?

Comment: The assembly code for the `tuple` version ends up about 1.5 KB smaller (32935 vs. 34617 bytes in size), so if nothing else, the larger unrolled loop, on top of needing to execute more instructions, might be making loops around it too large to fit in a nearer-to-chip cache, causing additional issues. It's *very* strange code regardless, I can't imagine why the code in question would need a `memcpy`-like operation in the first place, when it's literally just looping over a `dict` reading a `float` from a `tuple`, and incrementing another value.

Comment: Side-note: `s = 0.0` may be a better initializer, as it means `s` will remain a consistent type for the whole function.

Comment: @Simd: Done. Have at it.

Comment: I think you can also get the llvm IR. Is that interestingly different for the two cases?

Comment: @Simd: Maybe? I can't read LLVM IR, so I wouldn't know what to look for. You can reproduce all this yourself if you'd like to check.

Comment: I can't read LLVM IR either which is why I asked :) Maybe chatgpt understands it?